# Why do I get a NullException when using any() on byte[] element

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to test if my byte[] element ImageData contains any data. If there is no data my database shows it as NULL. I tried using the .Any() method, but for some reason this does not work. Why?

I have tried it with the following code

```
public FileStreamResult ViewImage(int id)
{
    Candidate candidate = _context.Candidate.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    bool hasImage = candidate.ImageData.Any();  // I get the NullException here          

    if (hasImage)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(candidate.ImageData);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, candidate.ImageType);
    }
    return null;            
}
```

If I use the logic  `if(candidate.ImageData == null)`, I get a `true` or `false`. I considered using Any() more elegant. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @derpirscher : it does with addition of John Skeet below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check for the NULL before calling the .Any(), so it won't throw the NullPointerException.

In trival methods you can use

```
bool hasImage = candidate.ImageData != null && candidate.ImageData.Any();
```

In the new way you can use the [Null Conditional operator C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) like

```
bool hasImage = candidate?.ImageData?.Any() == true;
```

,which keeps elegant as you wish.

Other way, you can use the Jon's method of [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

EDIT:
As suggested by Jon Skeet, changing the wrong operator name and correcting the last option to de-reference the bool? value.

Comment: That last approach won't compile, because the expression `candidate?.ImageData?.Any()` has a type of `bool?`, not `bool` - hence the `?? false` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Sathish for the insight in the `coalescing operator c#`. Very helpful.

Comment: That's not the null-coalescing operator though - it's the null-conditional operator. (It's definitely worth knowing about both :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you're calling a method on a null reference... In this case it's an extension method so you'll get an `ArgumentNullException` instead of a `NullReferenceException`, but it's behaving exactly [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

You can write your own extension method for this if you want:

```cs
public class NullSafeEnumerable
{
    public static bool NonNullAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) =>
        source is object && source.Any();
}
```

(That's not a great name, but you can come up with your own one.)

Or you could use the null-conditional operator:

```cs
bool hasImage = candidate.ImageData?.Any() ?? false;
```

or (equivalently):

```cs
bool hasImage = candidate.ImageData?.Any() == true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It is a bit baffling. The object should exist, but the contents may be null? In my case the object did not exist. That is the logic what I've learned.

Comment: @CharlesdeM.: It's not clear which object you're talking about - it sounds like the object referred to by the `candidate` variable, but that its `ImageData` returned a null reference rather than a reference to a byte array. That seems entirely reasonable if the value is NULL in the database. Note that a byte array object can't have "null contents", although it can be an array of length 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use C# 6.0 feature called [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/csharp-six#null-conditional-operator)

```cs
bool hasImage = candidate?.ImageData?.Any() == true;
```

If any of the objects before .Any() is null then the entire expression will return null.